# Error with Convolutional Neural Network (SGD?)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I'm implementing a CNN with Numpy and Scipy to solidify my understanding, but I'm encountering a rather strange problem.

My layers are: input -> conv -> pool -> FC

Here are the relevant functions:

```
def unpackTheta (theta, filterSize, numFilters, pooledDim, outputSize):
    a = filterSize ** 2 * numFilters
    b = a + numFilters
    c = b + pooledDim ** 2 * numFilters * outputSize
    d = c + outputSize
    return (np.reshape(theta[0 : a], (filterSize, filterSize, numFilters)),
            np.reshape(theta[a : b], (numFilters)),
            np.reshape(theta[b : c], (pooledDim ** 2 * numFilters, outputSize)),
            np.reshape(theta[c : d], (outputSize)))

def getConvolution (features, Wc, Bc, numFilters, numImages, filteredSize):
    conv = np.zeros((filteredSize, filteredSize, numFilters, numImages))
    for imageNum in range(numImages):
        image = features[:, :, imageNum]
        for filterNum in range(numFilters):
            filterLayer = np.rot90(Wc[:, :, filterNum], 2)
            conv[:, :, filterNum, imageNum] = sigmoid(convolve2d(image, filterLayer, 'valid') + Bc[filterNum])
    return conv

def getPooled (features, poolSize, pooledSize, filteredSize, numFilters, numImages):
    ret = np.empty((pooledSize, pooledSize, numFilters, numImages))
    poolFilter = np.ones((poolSize, poolSize)) / poolSize ** 2
    for i in range(numFilters): 
        for j in range(numImages):
            pooledLayer = convolve2d(features[:, :, i, j], poolFilter, 'valid')
            for x in range(0, filteredSize, poolSize):
                for y in range(0, filteredSize, poolSize):
                    ret[x / poolSize, y / poolSize, i, j] = pooledLayer[x, y]
    return ret

def getCost (theta, *args) :
    ## Initializing variables
    features, inputSize, filterSize, numFilters, poolSize, outputSize, reg = args
    filteredSize = inputSize - filterSize + 1
    pooledSize = filteredSize / poolSize
    (Wc, Bc, Wr, Br) = unpackTheta(theta, filterSize, numFilters, pooledSize, outputSize)
    numImages = np.size(features, 0)

    actualValues = np.eye(outputSize)[features[:, 0]]
    features = np.reshape(features[:, 1:] / 255.0, (inputSize, inputSize, numImages))

    ## Forward propagation
    # Convolution
    conv = getConvolution(features, Wc, Bc, numFilters, numImages, filteredSize)

    # Mean pooling
    pooled = np.reshape(getPooled(conv, poolSize, pooledSize, filteredSize, numFilters, numImages), (-1, numImages))

    # Logistic regression
    calcValues = sigmoid(pooled.transpose().dot(Wr) + Br)

    ## Calculating cost
    cost = -np.sum(actualValues * np.log(calcValues) + (1 - actualValues) * np.log(1 - calcValues)) / numImages
    cost += reg * (np.sum(Wc ** 2) + np.sum(Wr ** 2)) / (2 * numImages)

    ## Back propagation

    #print Wr
    #print Br
    outputError = (calcValues - actualValues) 

    pooledError = Wr.dot(outputError.transpose())
    pooledError = np.reshape(pooledError, (pooledSize, pooledSize, numFilters, numImages))

    convError = np.empty((filteredSize, filteredSize, numFilters, numImages))
    convErrorFilter = np.ones((poolSize, poolSize)) / (poolSize ** 2)
    for i in range(numFilters):
        for j in range(numImages):
            convError[:, :, i, j] = np.kron(pooledError[:, :, i, j], convErrorFilter)

    convError *= conv * (1 - conv)

    ## Gradient

    WrGrad = pooled.dot(outputError)
    BrGrad = np.sum(outputError, 0)

    WcGrad = np.zeros((filterSize, filterSize, numFilters))
    BcGrad = np.empty(numFilters)

    for i in range(numFilters):
        BcGrad[i] = np.sum(convError[:, :, i, :])
        for j in range(numImages): 
            filterLayer = np.rot90(convError[:, :, i, j], 2)
            WcGrad[:, :, i] += convolve2d(features[:, :, j], filterLayer, 'valid')

    WrGrad /= numImages
    WcGrad /= numImages
    BrGrad /= numImages
    BcGrad /= numImages

    WrGrad += reg * Wr / numImages
    WcGrad += reg * Wc / numImages

    global costCache
    costCache = cost
    return (cost, np.concatenate((WcGrad.flatten(), BcGrad.flatten(), WrGrad.flatten(), BrGrad.flatten()), axis=0))
```

I implemented a numerical gradient to verify if it was returning the right values, and it was. However, my softmax regression seems to be predicting the same value across the entire batch when I do SGD.

However, when I use scipy.minimize function, it gives me different values for softmax regression

Any help is greatly appreciated.